# OpenLayers FramedCloud Autosizing

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers

According to the documentation, I should be able to configure the size of my OpenLayers popup by declaring an `OpenLayers.Size` object in the FramedCloud constructor:

```
this.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud('featurePopup',
    this.options.feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
    new OpenLayers.Size(80, 60),
    html,
    null, true, this.onPopupClose
);
map.addPopup(this.popup, true);
```

Currently the popup that is rendered is autosized no matter what dimensions I use in the constructor.

[image]

I've tried manually setting the autosizing attribute of the FramedCloud to false as well as manually adjusting the css styling for the popup without achieving the results I need.

I checked and found some [similar issues](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/107) in the OpenLayers 2.11 issues list, but I haven't found a workaround.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how helpful this will be for others, but for this particular example, scrollbars were being rendered as a result of a floated div at the bottom of the dialog.  By updating the css I was able to draw clean autosized popups without having to calculate custom dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

```
            this.popup.autoSize = false;
```

Add this instruction before the addPopup().

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem and the only workaround I found is to use for instance AnchoredBubble.